# Host name of zabbix_agentd was changed is constantly triggered

Tags: zabbix

I have a problem where just about every single host I'm monitoring on my Zabbix system has this event triggered about once every 24hours
Nothing has changed on the hosts that should affect this and its rather strange thats it across all hosts.

If I look at the history of the trigger then values are identical, so nothing actually has changed

Any advice as to why this is happening on a fairly regular basis?

Zabbix Server 4.4.6, agents are 4.0.xx or 4.4.xx

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow. can you share a print screen of the item and the trigger? are them from the standard template coming from zabbix installation?

Comment: Hi,yes these are all from the standard template.
I acknowledged them all yesterday and again almost at the same time, all my hosts have lit up with Host name

Comment: 2020-03-16 18:47:37 Information  Host name of zabbix_agentd was changed on   13h 4m 57s
2020-03-16 17:45:48 Information  Host name of zabbix_agentd was changed on   14h 6m 46s
2020-03-16 16:52:02 Information  Host name of zabbix_agentd was changed on   15h 32s
2020-03-16 16:49:27 Information  Host name of zabbix_agentd was changed on   15h 3m 7s
2020-03-16 16:43:20 Information  Host name of zabbix_agentd was changed on   15h 9m 14s
2020-03-16 16:41:49 Information  Host name of zabbix_agentd was changed on   15h 10m 45s

Comment: please share the Latest Data too, and the agentd.conf; those host are changing name for some reason. are they virtual machines? are they provisioned?

Comment: Latest data, shows the relative same name for each host, so on that basis the name hasn't changed, but its being seen as one

This is the item
agent.hostname

And the trigger
{Template Module Zabbix agent:agent.hostname.change()}=0

Comment: @IronBishop the hosts are all different, some physical, some VMs, some are EC2s
All of these hosts were previously monitored on an old Zabbix server, this issues points more at a server problem than a host problem. The only thing thats changes on the config file has been the server they report to

Comment: If the latest data, viewing "last 500 item", displays the same name over and over, i'm lost.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately thats what it does show. Unless somehow the string comparison is seeing a difference

Comment: im having the same issue on my mac mini